# I am trying to compile with -fsanitizer=address, but keep getting "cannot find -lasan"

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, c++17

g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror -Weffc++ -pedantic -fsanitize=address getEvenNums.cpp

This is the error I am getting after trying to compile. I am using windows.

> C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lasan

Comment: Pretty sure asan isn't supported on Windows.

Comment: Im not sure my professor told me to use it but it is not working

Comment: Don't use Windows then.